# Unable to set overflow hidden when there is a div with negative margin on right

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a page where i have two divs which slide in, one from left and one from right, the div which slides from left to right doesn't give any problem, while the one which slides from right to left make the page overwflow horizontally.

I tought that was an issue of some of container so i tried to set the same div to slide instead from left to right and that works, the issue is only when there is a div with right position and negative right margins.

I have set the `overflow: hidden;` to html and body and tried with all other childs but nothing...

The page still behave like this:

[image]

The page start with normal view but i'm able to scroll horizontally to the div which have to be hidden and which then on a specific event i slide in the view...

The page has simple structure like:

```js
$('.scontrino').css('margin-right', -$('.scontrino').width() - 30);


$('.content').on('click', function() {
  $(".content").addClass("col-sm-8");
  $(".content").removeClass("col-sm-12");
  $('.scontrino').animate({
    marginRight: 0
  }, 300)
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100%;
  color: #001c1f;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.scontrino {
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.945);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-sm-12 content">
      CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 scontrino">
      SLIDER
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

But in the example i can't reproduce the horizontal scroll as the overflow: hidden works properly...

**EDIT:**
That happend only on mobile devices when i'm using chrome developer device toolbar

Comment: instead of `margin-right` try `transform:translate` css property.

Comment: @kunalpanchal just tried and having the same problem.. the page become scrollable horizontally and vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle class name to animate the slider as in the following code which might help you

```js
 
$('.content').on('click', function() {
  $(".content").addClass("col-sm-8");
  $(".content").removeClass("col-sm-12");
  $('.scontrino').addClass("animate-direction");
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100%;
  color: #001c1f;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.scontrino {
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.945);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: ease all 300ms;
}

.animate-direction{
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-sm-12 content">
      CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 scontrino">
      SLIDER
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: that's way better of using margins, but i have still the scrolling issue, BUT i noticed that i have that issue ONLY when i'm using device toolbar (simulating mobile device by using google chrome developer tools)